# Google search results API usage?

Tags: api, search

My question is regarding the [google AJAX search api](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/).  I have been trying to figure this out by exploring their site with no luck.  How can I use this API on my site but have the results only be the google results from within my site (i.e. only shows the `site:mydomain.com` results and NOT the results from a standard google.com search)? Is this even allowed per their terms of usage?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a Google custom search and [tie it to that](http://www.google.com/uds/samples/cse/index.html).